# Why save the personal access client id and secret in .env?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, oauth-2.0, nuxt.js, laravel-passport

I am new to laravel passport and i am figuring out how laravel passport works

**Question 1**

Why save the personal access client id and secret in .env according to the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#creating-a-personal-access-client)? if the id and secret is created by executing this command `php artisan passport:client --personal` and stored in the database

**Question 2**

According to docs, it is said to save it in .env file. which application is it saved in? the passport application or the frontend javascript application. I have 2 different projects one is the laravel passport(backend) and the other is the nuxtjs(frontend)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1**

You should never hardcode secrets; that is one of the most basic security best practices. The reason behind that is that when you push your code into any remote(usually Github), you let anybody see that secret.

Even if your repository is private, you may not want all members to have access to it or if you decide to make it public you won't want to worry about secrets being leaked. So it's best to not include them in the code.

More about your oAuth secret key [here](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/).

**Answer 2**

It is not loaded to any application by default. What you're doing is just saving the information to a file called `.env`. You then have to configure one of your applications to load environmental variables from it, probably using a library([how laravel does it](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#environment-configuration), [how you can load .env files in nuxt.js](https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module).

In your case, the Nuxt app does not need to have access to that secret so there is no need to load it there.

**Note that you will have to use [.gitignore](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/gitignore-what-is-it-and-how-to-add-to-repo/) or an equivelant to your source-control system in order to prevent the `.env` file from being uploaded to a remote and avoid the problems of answer 1.**

Comment: Thank you for your response. with more research now i have switched to using clieant credentails flow because there are resources that is not related to user for example in an ecommerce app a list of products and categories is not related to a particular user and it should be displayed on the front page of the front-end.

Comment: However the issue arises in storing the client_secret and client_id. In nuxtjs even if the those variables are stored in .env file, It is still exposed to the client's browser meaning anyone can take it. Now i have looked into storing it in httponly cookie but since nuxtjs is a javascript application it cant store in it. what would be solution for it?

Comment: @MohamedAiman The .env file is **not** loaded to your Nuxt app by default unless you do it with `@nuxtjs/dotenv` - you should not. This is the solution.